# Understanding C# Naming Terminology

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Is there a difference between "Visual C #" and ".net c#"

I am about to start learning .net c# and would like to clarify this before I start.

Comment: It's not important to understand that before beginning to learn it.

Comment: Where did you find _.NET C#_ ? Because that's not really an existing name.

Comment: .NET is the framework, C# is the language. Visual C# is just another name for C#.

Comment: Try looking through [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1zx9t92.aspx). The people at Microsoft went through the trouble of writing out some good thoughts.

Comment: "Visual C#" is the trademarked product name for Microsofts implementation of the compiler. Other compilers (like Mono) are not  called Visual.

Comment: Ah ok so it doesn't matter if I use a tutorial or buy a book with any of the following terms. Thank you guys. Would some one like to write an answer so I can close the question?

Comment: C# is a ECMA and ISO standard programming language. Visual C# is Microsoft's implementation of C#. .NET is a framework that can be targeted by multiple programming languages, C# being one of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C# is a programming language, the first language specification was done by [Microsoft in 2002](http://download.microsoft.com/download/a/9/e/a9e229b9-fee5-4c3e-8476-917dee385062/CSharp%20Language%20Specification%20v1.0.doc). There it is made clear that "Visual C#" is a trademark of Microsoft, they also refers to their other languages as "Visual Basic", "Visual C#" and "Visual C++" and the variations "Visual Basic .NET", "Visual C# .NET" and "Visual C++ .NET" refer to the implementation of the languages on the .NET framework.

In December 2002 the [ECMA standard for the C# language](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-WITHDRAWN/ECMA-334,%202nd%20edition,%20December%202002.pdf) appeared and later on April 2003 [the equivalent standard by ISO](http://www.techstreet.com/cgi-bin/pdf/free/378672/iso+iec+23270-2003.pdf). These opened the doors for third party implementation such as [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/) and the now defunct [DotGnu](http://www.dotgnu.org/). These standards refer to the language as just "C#".

Answer (score 1):

Visual C# is Microsoft's implementation of their own C# specification.  In theory, someone could follow the C# specification to create it's own C# implementation and give it a different name.

I'm not sure where you took the .NET C# name but you may consider it as a reference to visual C#.  For pragmatic purpose, people will usually refer to C# instead of Visual C# or .NET C# so C# is the only name you should care about at this point... unless you have plan to create your own implementation but that's not for beginners.